# Need to position html5 canvas within css div at bottom right

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

I am attempting to add a clock that uses HTML5 canvas to a div. The canvas tag has an ID so I have tried to apply the CSS tags position, bottom, right to the id. I can't seem to get the contents of the canvas tag to show up in the lower right corner of the parent DIV.

**HTML**

```
<div id="Header">
<canvas id="clock"></canvas>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#Header {
    background-image: url(images/building.png);
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 780px;
    height: 399px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 0 0 0;
    position: relative;
}

#clock {
    width: 780px;
    height: 399px;
    bottom: 1px;
    right: 1px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

I have tried all sorts of variations but no luck.

I have also tried removing all the properties for the id=clock and instead enclosing the canvas tag with a parent tag and applying the same properties. No luck.

When I create a div tag with the same CSS properties and remove the canvas tag and replace with just text, the text show up in the bottom right hand corner of the parent div as desired.

So, it seems something in the js code that's feeding the canvas tag is what's causing the positioning issue. Not sure.

Been at this for way too many hours banging my head on the keyboard, searching Google, trial and error etc.

Any help would be most appreciated.

If you need a look at the JS code that's generating the contents of the canvas tag, please let me know. I did not want to include it right off unless it's needed because I didn't want to clutter up the post any further.

Thanks!

Comment: 1) If the canvas is the same size as the header, it doesn't make a difference if you position it in the top-left or bottom-right. 2) You have to define the canvas dimensions as HTML attributes, or using JS; CSS dimensions will scale the contents along with the canvas.

Comment: Those width, height attributes got in there by mistake. Let me pull them out and have another look. I believe the size of the canvas is already defined in the JS file. I didn't have any luck before the width and height were in there but let me try again. Thanks. Will report back.

Comment: bfavaretto thanks! After looking at your response I went digging in the .js file and found that the size of the canvas was the size of the browser window which of course wouldn't allow me to move it. Can't move an item in a box which is the same size as the box :-) How do I select your response as "The Answer" in here?

Comment: By the way this is what I changed:

Comment: Nevermind, I posted a comment instead of an answer because I wasn't sure what the problem was.

Comment: Thanks to bfavaretto! I removed the width and height from the #canvas attributes, then change the `canvas.width = window.innerWidth * 0.8;` and `canvas.height = window.innerHeight * 0.8;` to a specific size and viola, it works now. Can't see how I didn't catch this or figure out on my own.. Sometimes you just need someone to tell you that you are being an idiot.. :-)

Comment: If bfavaretto doesn't want to post his answer as an answer you can answer your own question with the finding and mark that as answered. This way the question won't be listed as unanswered (open) and saves us all some time when we look for new questions to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-align` and `padding-top`. For example:

```css
#Header {
    border: 3px dotted red;
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 200px;
}

#clock {
   border: 1px solid black  
}
```

```html
<div id="Header">
<canvas id="clock"></canvas>
</div>
```